# ClickFunnels integration with rails2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

Is there a way to create a page in ClickFunnels(https://www.clickfunnels.com/) website and when I submit that page, I need to store the form details in my rails app(into a particular table). Which means I want to display my database in the clickfunnels integrations list. I googled hours but couldn't get much information on this.

can anyone suggest me if you have done this. A reference link also much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need a way to integrate into the ClickFunnels API

Answer (score 1):

We couldn't find any way to do this inside clickfunnels itself, if there is a easy way to add custom systems to their integrations I too look forward to seeing those answers.  Until then, here's what we did: We just put our custom form on their page and used ajax to send it back out the end point in our system it needed to hand that data too.

Then, since we also needed to submit the same info to click funnels, we build a fake CF form(I think we actually put one on the page, but used CSS to hide it, then filled it out dynamically from our custom form), and call submit on that form, sending the user through the normal click funnels submission process and sending them to the next page in the funnel.